# How to return an int that should be the sum of the values in an ArrayList

Tags: java

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> q3(ArrayList<Integer> listOfIntegers){
    ArrayList<Integer> listOfIntegers1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    listOfIntegers1.add(16);
    listOfIntegers1.add(6);
    listOfIntegers1.add(10);
    listOfIntegers1.add(12);
    return listOfIntegers1;
}
```

I have to take an ArrayList of Integers as a parameter and return an int. The returned int should be the sum of the values int the input ArrayList at indices 16, 6, 10, and 12. How would i go about doing this?

Comment: You iterate the list and add up the values.

Comment: Just add the values at those found indices and return the result. What's stopping you?

Comment: Why are you _adding_ those values to the list? And why are you creating a new list at all, if you just want to return a single number? Do you know what `add` does?

Comment: @tobias_k as I understand he wants to add the values at the indexes given in the second list (`listOfIntegers1`) above...  (Hint to OP): something like `listOfIntegers.get(listOfIntegers1.get(0)) + listOfIntegers.get(listOfIntegers1.get(1)) + ...`

Comment: and another hint to the author: use some meaningful names for variables, parameters and method... helps a lot ALWAYS

Comment: Yea sorry guys i realized i could have made this clearer, im very new to java and coding in general, i apologize and will try to make the question clearer next time, thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`IntStream::sum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#sum--) after filtering the values using the list of indexes:

```
List<Integer> listOfIntegers = Arrays.asList(0,1,2,3,4,5,100,7,8,9,100,11,100,13,14,15,100,17);
List<Integer> listOfIndexes = Arrays.asList(16,6,10,12);

return listOfIntegers
        .stream()
        .filter(i -> listOfIndexes.contains(listOfIntegers.indexOf(i))
        .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
        .sum();
```

Output:

> 400

Or even better to avoid iterating the whole `listOfIntegers`:

```
return listOfIndexes
         .stream()
         .mapToInt(idx -> listOfIntegers.get(idx))
         .sum();
```

But this way could cause an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if a given index is out of the range of the `listOfIntegers`.

Comment: OP only wants sum "at indices 16, 6, 10, and 12"

Comment: @tobias_k my bad. Edited already.